# Diffeomorphism between $S^n \backslash B_r(x)$ and some ball $B$ for arbitrary $x \in S^n$.

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, differential-topology

I was going through my lecture notes and in a proof I have written down that

"... Since we have a diffeomorphism between $S^n \backslash B^{n+1}_r(x)$ and some ball for arbitary $x \in S^n$ ..."

and I was wondering about said diffeomorphism. Could anybody help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does $B_r(x)$ denote a ball in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$?

Comment: Yes, I'll edit the original post.

Comment: 1) Move $x$ to infinity by some rotation to show that the first thing is diffeomorphic to $S^n$ minus some ball around infinity. 2) Use stereographic projection to prove that the result is diffeomorphic to a ball.

Comment: What do you mean by "move to infinity"?

Comment: Infinity would be the north pole, if I understood it right. It should work, but with a ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$, not $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. And a closed one.